# How to display data from api in react component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am using axios to get data from an API and the retrieved data was successfully dispatched to the store, I currently have some problems in displaying the data in my React component.

I was able to `console.log` the data successfully but it turns out my component renders before the data was fully retrieved from the API.

**Below is the component to display the data:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import HeaderSidebar from './includes/header-navbar';
import AllBooks from './includes/all-books';
import { getAllBooks } from '../../actions/book_actions';


class AdminHome extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.actions.getAllBooks();
}

renderBooks(){
    const allbooks = this.props.books;

    return allbooks.map((book) => {
        return (<div key={book.id}>
            <AllBooks title={book.title}
            description={book.description}
            />
        </div>)
    })
}
render() {
    return (
        <div >
            <HeaderSidebar />
          {this.renderBooks()}
            })}
            })}
        </div >
    )
  }
}

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
    books: state.book.data
  }
}

 AdminHome.PropTypes = {
  books: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators({
        getAllBooks
    }, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AdminHome);
```

**Actions**

```
export function getAllBooks() {
  return dispatch => axios.get(`${API_URL}`)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ALL_BOOKS,
        data: res.data
      });
      return res.data;
    })
    .catch(error => error);
}
```

**Reducers**
    import { ADD_BOOK,
      GET_ALL_BOOKS
    } from '../actions/types';

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {};

function bookReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_BOOK:
      return { ...state, message: 'Book added Successfully' };
    case GET_ALL_BOOKS:
      return { ...state, data: action.data };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default bookReducer;
```

Comment: Update your question with reducer and action.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering json data with axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959676/rendering-json-data-with-axios)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show something else until the data is done loading

```
renderBooks(){
if(!this.props.books) {
  return (<p>Loading data..<p/>);
}


// rest of your code here
```

Or you can initialize the property with an empty array so that at least nothing crashes until the data is done loading.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    books: state.book.data || []  //  maybe have to extra checks here if state.book doesn't exist yet
}
```

(Or do both, and change `if(!this.props.books)`  to `if(this.props.books.length < 1)`.