# How to insert value from state into a function?

Tags: reactjs

I have an array that is generated from a firebase database query.

I want to save that in state so that as the data changes, it will re-render the screen.

I can't seem to get the value from state into my function.  If I put the value from the array, it works, but then it won't automatically re-render when data changes.

Screen shot of it using the array... note the console log is printing that the state is set correctly.
[image]

and here it is with the error
[image]

It's gotta be right around line 101, but I cannot figure out the right syntax to make thsi work.

**UPDATE: I was not initializing state, that was one part of the error.**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Flexbox from 'flexbox-react';

import firebaseApp from '../api/firebase';
import GeoFire from 'geofire';

var geoRef = firebaseApp.database().ref('shiftgeo');
var geoFire = new GeoFire(geoRef);
var ref = geoFire.ref();  // ref === firebaseRef
var shiftKeys = []; // this array will hold the keys from the geoFire results
var shifts = []; // this array will hold the actual shift data of shifts in the geo, then we will filter it later

console.log(firebaseApp);

export class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      fname: 'Chris',
      lname: 'Chong',
      cellphone: '503 830 4313',
      email: 'chris@ehotleads.com',
      dataSource: ''
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    let email = 'chris@ehotleads.com';
    let password = '123456789';
    firebaseApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then((data) => {
            //this.setState({ error: 'Account already exists. Logging you in...', loading: false });
            console.log('success data', data);
            this.setState({
              user: data,
            });
          })
          .catch((data) => {
            //this.setState({ error: 'Authentication failed.', loading: false });
            console.log('error data', data);
          });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var geoQuery = geoFire.query({
      center: [45.616422, -122.580453],
      radius: 1000,
      });
    geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
      // dont forget that as shifts are added that match the geo, this will automatically add to the shiftKeys array
      //shiftKeys = [];
      shiftKeys.push(key)
      console.log("Found shift " + key + " at " + location + " (" + distance + " km away)");
    });

    geoQuery.on("ready", () => {
      shifts = []; // we need to blow out the array every time this function runs or it will throw errors
      shiftKeys.forEach((shiftKey) => {
        //console.log(shiftKey);
        let shiftsRef = firebaseApp.database().ref('shifts').child(shiftKey);
        shiftsRef.on("value", (snapshot) => {
          //console.log(snapshot.val())
          //if (snapshot.val().state == "WA" && (snapshot.val().licenseRequired == "CNA" || snapshot.val().licenseRequired == "RN")) {
          //if (snapshot.val().licenseType == this.state.licenseType || snapshot.val().licenseRequired == "TEST") {
          shifts.push({
            key: snapshot.key,
            fname: snapshot.val().fname,
            lname: snapshot.val().lname,
            company: snapshot.val().company,
            address1: snapshot.val().address1,
            address2: snapshot.val().address2,
            city: snapshot.val().city,
            state: snapshot.val().state,
            zip: snapshot.val().zip,
            shiftDate: snapshot.val().shiftDate,
            shiftStart: snapshot.val().shiftStart,
            shiftLength: snapshot.val().shiftLength,
            shiftDescription: snapshot.val().shiftDescription,
            licenseType: snapshot.val().licenseType,
            logo: snapshot.val().logo,
            building: snapshot.val().building,
          }) // end shifts.push
          var date_sort_asc = function (date1, date2) {
            if (date1.shiftDate > date2.shiftDate) return 1;
            if (date1.shiftDate < date2.shiftDate) return -1;
            return 0;
          };
        //}
          //console.log(this.state.distancePref)
          this.setState({
            dataSource: shifts,
            resultCount: shifts.length,
          })
        }); // end shiftsRef.on
      }); // end shiftKeys map
    }); // end geoQuery.on
    console.log('ShiftArray: ', shifts)
    console.log('StateArray: ', this.state.dataSource)
  }


  render() {
    const listItems = this.state.dataSource.map((shift) =>
      <li key={shift.key}>
        {shift.address1}
      </li>
    );
    console.log('ShiftArray: ', shifts)
    console.log('StateArray: ', this.state.dataSource)

    return (
  <Flexbox flexDirection="column" minHeight="100vh">
    <Flexbox element="header" height="60px">
      Header link one
    </Flexbox>

    <Flexbox flexGrow={1}>
      <Flexbox
        width="20%"
        minWidth="200px"
        maxWidth="300px"
        style={{ backgroundColor: '#ba0000' }}>
          Sidebar Menu Goes Here
      </Flexbox>
      <Flexbox width="80%" flexDirection="row" style={{ backgroundColor: '#FFF' }}>
        <div>List of Shifts Addresses</div>
        <ul>{listItems}</ul>
      </Flexbox>
    </Flexbox>

  <Flexbox element="footer" height="60px">
    Footer
  </Flexbox>
</Flexbox>
    );
  }
}
```

Now Im getting Uncaught TypeError: this.state.dataSource.map is not a function

Comment: or maybe the wrong approach to loop an array that is set in state to begin with?

Comment: Make sure you've initialized the state. Fetching data takes time. You can also do a conditional render like in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46143513/how-to-display-data-from-api-in-react-component/46143565#46143565  That should at least stop the component from crashing. But for more help you'd need to show more of the fetching logic. Where is it? In `componentDidMount` ?

Comment: That did help but now its a different error: Uncaught TypeError: this.state.dataSource.map is not a function

I will post the code.

Comment: Looks like you initialize `dataSource` to a String. An empty array would be more fitting in this case. Strings don't have a `map` function. Which is what the error is telling you. May be other issues. I'm not familiar with Firebase, so can't say much about that code.

Comment: Btw, if the password and mail in the code example are real, you probably want to change those to fake values. For safety/privacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I failed to initialize `dataSource` in the state, and then after that, I initialized it with a string instead of an empty array.

Was missing: `dataSource: []` in this.setstate in the constructor.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Maybe you already know this, but you can accept your answer (after 48 hours). https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer